# Prove that a measureable set depends at most on countably many coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

There is a question in my advanced probability text  that says that the following assertion:

$$f_n \text{ are measurable for all } n \in \mathbb{N} \implies \sup_n f_n \text{ is measurable }$$

fails for uncountable index set. The hint provided is to go about proving that a measruable set depends on countably many coordinates. Any hints on how to proceed on this *hint*?

I know there is a proof by example of a particular set of functions $\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ where $A$ is a non-measurable set, but I would like to obtain the solution via the route indicated by this hint.

Comment: I for one have no idea what that hint is supposed to mean.

Comment: That is a weird hint. I mean, take any non-measurable set $A$. Since $A$ cannot be a countable set, then $\{\chi_{\{a\}}\}_{a\in A}$ is uncountable set of functions with $\chi_{A}=\sup_{a\in A}\chi_{\{a\}}$ and so proving the assertion by giving a counterexample. What is that hint really for?

Comment: I dont know. Its just there staring back at me

Comment: @Greg its supposed to me (I guess) that to describe the set you need at most countable coordinates $(x_1, x2_, .... )$.

Comment: I can prove the assertion that "measurable set depends on countably many coordinates" (by guessing its meaning up to my interpretation) but I cannot see why this hint helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is analogous to Ex1.2 from Kallenberg's Foundations of Modern Probability, to be honest, I don't know the purpose of the hint. But Example 78 in the link might provide you with a counterexample.

[https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/754/notes/lecture-07.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/754/notes/lecture-07.pdf)

Consider the Wiener process $W(t,\omega), M(\omega)\equiv \sup_{t\in[0,1]} W(t,\omega)$. We can construct a version of $W$ for which the supremum is not measurable. Assume that $\Omega$ can be partitioned into an uncountable collection of disjoint measurable sets, one for each $t\in[0,1]$. Select any non measurable real-valued function $B(\omega)$, so long as $B(\omega)>M(\omega)$ for all $\omega$. Set $W^*(t,\omega) = W(t,\omega)$ if $\omega \notin \Omega_t$, and $=B(\omega)$ if $\omega \in \Omega_t$. Now, at every t, $P(W(t,\omega)=W^*(t,\omega))=1$. $W^*$ is a version of W. But for every $\omega$, there is a t such that $W^*(t,\omega) = B(\omega)>\sup_t W(t,\omega)$, so $\sup_t W^*(t,\omega)=B(\omega)$, which is not measurable.

Comment: Please add a summary instead of simply pasting the link.